# Modem only allows outgoing traffic from specific IP, how should I configure the switch behind it?

Tags: networking, router, modem

I've got a satellite modem with an 8 port router behind it. The modem has an IP of 192.168.128.100 and only allows traffic from 192.168.128.200.

So I connected the modem to the WAN port of the router, set up my router IP as 192.168.128.200 and the gateway as 192.168.128.100. Devices on the router use DHCP with the IP address set per MAC address, in the 192.168.128.201-209 range. **Unfortunately none of those devices are able to ping outside past the modem. Does the modem see all traffic as 192.168.128.200 or does it see it as the addresses behind the router?**

For reference, the hardware is a Hughes 9502 BGAN Satellite modem, the router is a [DLink DSR-150](http://us.dlink.com/us/en/business-solutions/security/services-routers/dsr-150.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making some reasonable assumptions, I believe the answer must be along the following lines -

1. Connect the satellite modem into the WAN port of the DSR-150.
2. Plug the other computers into the LAN ports on the DSR-150
3. Configure the WAN gateway with an IP address of 192.168.128.200 and
   gateway of 192.168.128.100 (netmask would, I expect, be 255.255.255.0)
4. Configure the LAN port on a different netmask.  For the sake of simplicity
   I'd configure the LAN port on the router to be 10.0.1.254 with a subnet
   of 10.0.0.0/24 (or 255.255.255.0), with a DHCP range of 10.0.0.1 to 
   10.0.0.100
5. Ensure the router is configured to do NAT (Network Address Translation)

I'm pretty sure your problem is that the IP address of the clients is in the 192.168.128 subnet - it needs to be on a different subnet.

Comment: This, you're trying to merge yourself into the providers network and thus the router ISNT doing NAT and the private IPs(eg 192.168.128.101) isnt being translated to your WAN IP(.128.200).

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right, using the same subnet was a Bad Item™